# Showing that $ \text{Ind}_H^G W \cong \text{Ind}_K^G(\text{Ind}_H^K W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, modules, representation-theory, vector-space-isomorphism

Suppose we have the tower $H \subseteq K \subseteq G$. I'm trying to show that $ \text{Ind}_H^G W \cong \text{Ind}_K^G(\text{Ind}_H^K W)$. I first wrote it out more explicitly, i.e.
$$ \text{Ind}_H^G W = \bigoplus_{\sigma \in G/H} W^\sigma$$
$$ \text{Ind}_K^G(\text{Ind}_H^K W) = \bigoplus_{\lambda \in G/K} \left( \bigoplus_{\sigma \in K/H} W^\sigma \right)^\lambda $$
Note that the $\sigma$ and $\lambda$ below the direct sums mean coset representatives rather than actual cosets. Also, $W^\sigma = W$, etc. I thought that perhaps we need to use a $G$-intertwiner; mine is as follows:
$$ T : \bigoplus_{\lambda \in G/K} \left( \bigoplus_{\sigma \in K/H} W^\sigma \right)^\lambda \rightarrow \bigoplus_{\sigma \in G/H} W^\sigma $$ 
$$ T \left( \sum_{\lambda \in G/K}\left( \sum_{\sigma \in K/H} v_\sigma \right)_\lambda \right)(x) = \sum_{x \in G/H} v_x $$
where the subscripts mean for example $v_\sigma \in W^\sigma$. The action of $G$ is given by $gw_\sigma = hw_\tau$, where $h \in H$ and the $\tau$ subscript means that $w$ now lies in a different copy of $W$. For $T$ to be an intertwiner, we want "$gT(v)=T(gv)$". Checking this, we have:
$$ gT \left( \sum_{\lambda \in G/K}\left( \sum_{\sigma \in K/H} v_\sigma \right)_\lambda \right)(x) = g \sum_{x \in G/H} v_x = \sum_{\tau \in G/H} hv_\tau $$ and
$$ T \left( g \sum_{\lambda \in G/K}\left( \sum_{\sigma \in K/H} v_\sigma \right)_\lambda \right)(x) = T \left( \sum_{\lambda \in G/K}\left( \sum_{\tau \in K/H} hv_\tau \right)_\lambda \right)(x) = \sum_{x \in G/H} hv_x $$
So $T$ is an intertwiner. Before I attempt an inverse, would anybody be able to let me know if any of the above is correct? Also, I feel that if the above is correct, then bijectivity seems relatively clear (?) so we don't even need to show it has an inverse?

Many thanks for any help.

Edit: I've just realised that this is a slight [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388538/induction-in-stages-textrmind-hg-textrmind-ng-textrmind-hn?rq=1), but the answer in that question uses category theory and my working is a little shorter, so I'd like to know if any of my method is correct.

Comment: I think the problem with the sort-of-duplicate is that it doesn't really use category theory. With category theory, I'd first quote the definition of induced representation: $\text{Ind}_H^G$ is the left adjoint of restriction $\text{Res}_H^G$. Then I'd notice that $\text{Res}_H^G=\text{Res}_H^K\circ\text{Res}_K^G$ trivially. The result follows by general nonsense about adjoints.

Comment: The general nonsense about adjoints is that adjoints compose.

Comment: One first thing I see is that your notation is bad. The $v_{\sigma}$ depends both on $\sigma$ and $\lambda$, and so it should be called $v_{\sigma, \lambda}$. Also, it isn't clear how you actually define your intertwiner.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I've attempted an edit - I think that main source of my confusion is due to this [side question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610679/confusion-about-defining-a-particular-intertwiner) I have asked. I've edited this solution to try and make it more similar to the intertwiner in my other question, but I'm not sure if it has been succesful (I tried to deal with the $v_\sigma$ problem by writing a new coset representative $x$ relating to the $x$ in the definition.

Comment: @Qiaochuyuan  : also that they are unique up to natural isomorphism !

Comment: Having accepted an answer to my other question, I think my edit has actually made the solution worse since it assumes that the space of induced representations is a space of functions, which is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing too much work, and so is that other answer. Here is a general fact about adjoints:

> If $R_1 : C_1 \to C_2$ and $R_2 : C_2 \to C_3$ are functors with left adjoints $L_1 : C_2 \to C_1$ and $L_2 : C_3 \to C_2$, then the composite $R_2 \circ R_1 : C_1 \to C_3$ has left adjoint $L_1 \circ L_2 : C_3 \to C_1$.

The proof is very straightforward:

$$\text{Hom}(L_1(L_2(-)), (-)) \cong \text{Hom}(L_2(-), R_1(-)) \cong \text{Hom}((-), R_2(R_1(-)).$$

Syntactically it's identical to the proof that the adjoint of a composition of linear operators is the composition of the adjoints in the opposite order.

Now, as Andreas observes in the comments, the restriction functor from $G$ to $H$ is the composite of the restriction from $G$ to $K$ and the restriction from $K$ to $H$, and induction is the left adjoint of restriction. So we're done.

This is a nice example of the value of using universal properties instead of constructions to prove things.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Indeed, this is a very clean and quick proof. I'm still going to keep the question open as I'm also interested in how to construct the intertwiner explicitly.

Comment: @mathphys: you can get something explicit here by being explicit about all of the adjunction isomorphisms above, which is not too hard, and just tracing through the proof. As one of the deleted answers says, it's convenient to use the extension-of-scalars / tensor product definition of induction to do this.