# About the proof of Induction in Stages: $\textrm{Ind}_H^G = \textrm{Ind}_N^G \textrm{Ind}_H^N$

Tags: representation-theory

I have some questions about the proof of Induction in Stages:

[Induction in Stages: $\textrm{Ind}_H^G = \textrm{Ind}_N^G \textrm{Ind}_H^N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388538/induction-in-stages-textrmind-hg-textrmind-ng-textrmind-hn?rq=1)

We are fixing a representation space $(π,W)$ 
of $H$. <- ?? $(σ,W)$ of $H$ ?

1. $T_{\sigma}(F)$ lies in $\textrm{Ind}_H^N(\sigma)$. <-?? lies in $\textrm{Ind}^G_N(σ)$ ?

$T_{\sigma}(g \cdot F)(g') = (g \cdot F)(g')(1_N) = F(g'g)(1_N) = T_{\sigma}(F)(g'g) = g \cdot T_{\sigma}(F)(g)$ <-?? $=g \cdot T_{\sigma}(F)(g′)$ ?

and don't you need a constraint
$$F(gn)=π(n)F(g)$$
where $g∈G$,$n∈N$ and $(π,F(g))$ is a representation of $N$, to show $F:G→\textrm{Ind}^N_H(σ)$ lies in $\textrm{Ind}_N^G \textrm{Ind}_H^N(\sigma)$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you ediit your question. What do all those <- ?? mean?

Comment: It means that "maybe the right hand side <- ?? *** ? is ture?".

Comment: In what way does this site guarantee the mathematical correctness? Similar sites like 'Stack Overflow', the correctness of the answer can be checked by executing it on one's computer. It means that the computer is a reviewer, but are there any reviewer on this site?